# How to make my python code faster by using multi threading?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

This is the only function in my program I am calling, and the argument 'apps' I am passing is directory which contains 5000 json files on which I will be doing some arithmetic and It take me around 25mins to process all the files.
Now I want to do same thing using multi threading to make it faster.
Can someone please help me with this.

```
def directory(apps):
    for files in os.listdir(apps):
        files_path = os.path.join(apps, files) 
        with open(files_path, 'r') as data_file:

       #Doing some stuff



try:
    time.sleep(1)
    start_time = time.time()
    directory(application)
    print "===== %s seconds =====" % (time.time() - start_time)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '\nInterrupted'
    print "===== %s seconds =====" % (time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: Look at **generators** first, to split the _directory_ function in one that delivers one file at a time. Then start a few threads that individually call _directory_ until it runs out of files...

Comment: What are you doing after opening the file? Is it CPU or I/O bound job?

Comment: I am just verifying some data in file. It data is present , I save that data in some other folder.